# Cannot convert instance of a document class to instance of its subclass - Mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I am using Flask + mongoengine to create a web application. Here is a part of my models

```
class Order(Document):
    placed_on=DateTimeField(required=True)
    order_id = SequenceField()
    status = StringField(default="Request Received")
    cart = ListField(DictField())
    userMobile = StringField(required=True)
    userEmail = StringField(required=True)
    address = ReferenceField(Address)
    sheet_id = IntField(default=0)
    remarks = StringField(default="")

    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

class ConfirmedOrder(Order):
    delivery_slot_start = DateTimeField()
    delivery_slot_end = DateTimeField()

    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}
```

I have an instance of class Order as order. I now want to convert it to a ConfirmedOrder.This is the code I am using for the conversion

```
try:
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    cOrder = ConfirmedOrder(**order.to_mongo())
    cOrder.delivery_slot_start = timest
    cOrder.delivery_slot_end = timend
    cOrder.save();
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

I However, get this error:

```
The field '_id' does not exist on the document 'Order.ConfirmedOrder'
```